# C# string.length > 0 seen as boolean

Tags: c#

I am new to C# but not to programming.  When I compare the lengths of two strings in the code below, I get the error:

> Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

Apparently `string1.Length > 0` is seen as a boolean in this context.

How should I perform this comparison?

```
if (string1.Length > 0 & string2.Length = 0)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `==` rather than `=`?

Comment: I am not familiar with C#, but isn't it == and && the operator ?

Comment: C# Operators http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx

Comment: Use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter)` or at least do a comparison to `String.Empty` instead of checking the lengths.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When applied to integers, the `&` operator in C# is a bitwise `AND`, not a logical `AND`. Also `=` is an assignment, not an equality comparison operator. The `string1.Length > 0` expression is indeed an expression of boolean type, while the assignment is integer (because `0` is integer).

What you need is

```
if (string1.Length > 0 && string2.Length == 0)
```

Comment: `&` is both in C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(v=vs.80).aspx.

Comment: `&` is not just bitwise, it's also the non-short-circuiting logical AND, as Oli points out.

Answer (score 10):

The reason for the error is because you have written `=` when you meant `==`.  In C#

```
string1.Length > 0 & string2.Length = 0
```

means

```
(string1.Length > 0) & (string2.Length = 0)
```

The type of the left side is `bool` and the type of the right side is `int`, which cannot be `&`-ed together, hence the error.  Of course even if you managed to get past that, `Length` cannot be the target of an assignment either.

Use `==` to test for equality. `=` is assignment.

Consider also using `&&` instead of `&`.  The meaning of `x & y` is "evaluate both, the result is `true` if both are `true` and `false` otherwise". The meaning of `x && y` is "evaluate the left side; if it is `false` then the result is `false` so do not evaluate the right side. If the left side is `true` then proceed as `&` does."

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant to do this:

```
if (string1.Length > 0 && string2.Length == 0)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

In C#, the [`=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) operator is just for assignment. The [`==`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) is used for equality comparisons. You probably also want to use the [`&&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) operator instead of [`&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) (`&&` will skip the second condition if the first condition evaluates to false).

However, if really want to 'compare the lengths of the strings', you can just do this:

```
if (string1.Length > string2.Length)
{
    //Do Something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem.

```
if(string1.Length > 0 && string2.Length == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  Adding the additional = sign thereby doing a comparison as opposed to an assignment fixed my problem.... Now if I can just figure out how to mark this question as answered ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a [==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664713%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for your equality test? C# assignment [returns a value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691315%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) [(as in C)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_%28computer_science%29#Value_of_an_assignment).